# Showing that a field $k$ is a splitting field for $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $\gamma$ is the fifth root root of unity.  That is, $\gamma = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$, so $\gamma$ is a root of $p(x) = x^5-1$, or more precisely of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ since we can factor out a $(x-1)$ which has the obvious root of $1$.

I need to show that $k = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ is a splitting field for $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know I will probably have to consider the basis of this extension, which will be:

$\{1, \gamma, \gamma^2, \gamma^3, \gamma^4\}$

But I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.  What I want to show is that my polynomial $p(x)$ can be factored into irreducible linear factors $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...$ over $k$.

Comment: Hint: This irreducible polynomial generates a cyclic galois extension, and you can explicitly write down the generator.

Comment: You just wrote down the five roots of that fifth degree polynomial! Is that not enough to make it split?

Answer (score 2):

Because $(\gamma^n)^5 = (\gamma^5)^n = 1$, we have
$$
x^5 - 1 = (x-1)(x-\gamma)(x-\gamma^2)(x-\gamma^3)(x-\gamma^4)
$$
and so $x^5-1$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$.

Comment: It seems I was overthinking it.  Thank you, that makes perfect sense.